# django: save one field of a formset at a time

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

My django app connects to a sql server database. On my template I have an editable datatable/formset. Whenever a user edits a field and hits enter, I want only the edited field to be saved. As far as I know AJAX is the only approach to do this, especially if you want the value of the edited field to be the only one transfered to the server. Let's put this case aside for now and accept transferring all data of the formset at once.
Also, the formset is based on a sql server view that includes calculated values. Hence, executing formset.save() will raise an error. Instead I have to use the underlying table to save the modified value. What would be best practice to identify the changed field and save only this one?

Let's say the underlying table is costsperdiem that corresponds to a model in my django app and 'costs' is the name of the editable field I want to save then my approach is as follows:

1. check if the formset is valid
2. loop through the forms of the formset using changed_data to seek for the modified field
3. using a model instance to filter for the modified record
4. pass the modified value to the model
5. save the model

which looks like this in code:

```
formset = FormSet_CostsPerDiem(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
    for f in formset.forms:
        if 'costs' in f.changed_data:
            val2save=f.cleaned_data['costs']
            id=f.cleaned_data['id_costsperdiem']
            rec2save=costsperdiem.objects.filter(pk=id)
            rec2save.costs=val2save
            rec2save.save()
```

What is best practice to do something like this?

Comment: Not sure about "best practice", but you could just query the model instance of the form and compare the value of `f.instance.costs` to `f.cleaned_data['costs']`. If it's different, then `f.instance.costs = f.cleaned_data['costs']; f.instance.save();` without saving the entire form.

Comment: @ViktorPetrov Seems to me like `f.instance.costs` already contains the new value, i.e. `f.instance.costs` and `f.cleaned_data['costs']` will be always the same.

Comment: hmm, strange. If you're not saving the form the instance shouldn't have new values. Maybe try querying the instance instead, e.g. `instance = Instance.objects.get(pk=id)` and comparing that to the form's cleaned data? You could also overwrite the form __init__ to store the initial instance fields/values and overwrite the save method to check against the stored values before saving.

Comment: Querying the instance is what I already do (`costsperdiem` is the instance). But you are right about using `get` instead of `filter` (I changed that). But I don't see any benefit in using the form's init and overwriting the save method.